# How to disable laptop's built-in keyboard in Chrome OS flex

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome-os-flex

I have recently switched to Chrome OS Flex. In windows, I used Keytweak to disable my built-in keyboard and use my external keyboard. However, here I tried `xinput`. But its terminal said,"WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details." I tried to search everything in google and found some answers. But I understood nothing. Those were not detailed enough. Also, I am not a pro Linux user. I can just do some basic things. So can anyone help me solve this painful problem? Also, I am learning python. So it's not possible for me to use on screen keyboard either. Or if you can give me any solution to auto key pressing problem(without disabling the built-in keyboard) that's fine too.